# Advance CodeIgniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have created image gallery using CodeIgniter default pagination. The images are came from db and each page have 16 images.

Recently my customer ask me to put 32 images per each page other than the first page.
This means that on the first page it only have 16 images and the other pages come after that have 32 images per page. So I change the code little bit and get the result as he asked.

But the problem came in pagination bar. When I was in 2nd page still pagination show that I am in the 1st page.

```
if ($this->uri->segment(3, 0) == 0){
    $config['per_page'] = 16;
    }else{
    $config['per_page'] = 32;
    }
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $query = $this->db->get('img', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));//when i am in page 2 "segment(3)" will equal to 16
```

Is their is any other alternative pagination library that can do this? The page is at http://vintagepostersofceylon.com/posters/cinema/

Answer (score 0):

try playing with the `$config['uri_segment']` Try `4`

And if you still don't get it, it will help if you give us the URL.

Update: new info

I'm confused as well as to why it isn't working. Try using this:

```
if (((int)$this->uri->segment(3)) > 16)
{
    $config['per_page'] = 32;
}
else
{
    $config['per_page'] = 16;
}

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: I can't see the URL you posted.